# Spring MVC - unable to render view

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, view

I am learning spring-mvc, I created a crud project using STS and it is working fine.

I need to create another view just for testing and playing with spring:

1. I added a new jsp file in the same location as the other jsp file (WEB-INF/views), called company.jsp
2. I created a new controller to handle the requests:

> ```
> package com.test.issa;
>
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
> import org.springframework.ui.Model;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
>
> @Controller
> public class CompanyController {
>
>   @RequestMapping(value = "/company", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>     public String GetCompany(Model model) {
>       model.addAttribute("name", "Hello World!");
>         return "company";
>     }
> }
> ```

But when I call the view http://localhost:9999/app/company it is giving error 404, am I missing anything?

Here is also my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>    </beans:beans>
```

Comment: try to add @RequestMapping("/") under controller class

Comment: where exactly should I add it, and should I remove @RequestMapping(value = "/company", method = RequestMethod.GET)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only component scanning the package declared here

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />
```

But your `@Controller` is defined in

```
package com.test.issa;
```

You need to add that package to the `component-scan`, otherwise there won't be a bean created for the `@Controller` annotated type and the MVC stack won't register its handler methods.

Either that or declare an explicit `<bean>` for your `CompanyController` type.

Comment: how can I declare an explicit <bean> for my CompanyController type?

Comment: @AliIssa The same way you do for the other beans in your XML configuration.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help, It worked perfectly! Now for declaring an explicit <bean>, What should I add inside the id, class and the inner bean properties